# A part with sections and subsections but without chapters in ToC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, hyperref, amsbook

My document consists of three parts. Parts 1 and 3 contain chapters and sections. Part 2 however is a bound in research paper, and as such only contains sections and subsections, however no chapters. I use the `hyperref` package, and in the Table of Contents everything is displayed fine. However the PDF reader interprets the first section, "Introduction and motivation", as chapter and all following sections as subsections thereof:

[image: table of content, PDF reader]

How can I sort this out?

The document class used is `amsbook`.

Comment: In what way does the PDF reader consider the sections as chapters? By means of the location within the bookmarks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a section level is skipped, `hyperref` is not happy:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater 
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 12.
```

Package `bookmark` implements a better algorithm that deals with this case and support other features (different actions, formatting of the bookmark, fewer LaTeX runs, …):

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
  numbered,
  open
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{First part}
\chapter{Chapter in first part}
\section{Section in first part}

\part{Second part}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{Section in second part}
\section{Second section in second part}

\part{Third part}
\chapter{Chapter in third part}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Bookmarks]

Comment: It was as easy as that! Thanks for your great help! :) Maybe you can also help me out here: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71644/alternative-text-to-be-displayed-in-the-pdf-viewers-table-of-content)